# How to run multi tags in serenity?

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd

I have two scenario outline, whether the scenarios was tagged by @Login, @DashBoard. when I run the project it always executes @DashBoard scenario then executes @Login.

I tried  @WithTags(
{@WithTag("login"),@WithTag("login")}) this option in before  @CucumberOptions but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

@WithTags is for JUnit, not Cucumber - see the Cucumber docs to see how to define tags in the @CucumberOptions parameters.

But you cannot control the order of execution of feature files using tags - feature files (and scenarios) are meant to be independent, so your Create-Blog-Category.feature should not depend on the login.feature to work (feature files are not test scripts). Each scenario needs to be independent. See https://johnfergusonsmart.com/1136-2/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag expressions to specify which tags to run (or not).
For example `@CucumberOptions(tags = "@smoke and @fast")`.
For mor information see the [Cucumber documentation about tags](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags)